# How to check if your site is loaded in iframe and fetch parent URL?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am currently developing an app that will be loaded through iframe and I am interested in fetching URL from parent site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`top != self` -> true if framed

`top.location.href` -> get url of top page

`window.parent.location.href` -> get url of parent